# A question about field of fractions of a ring of functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, polynomial-rings

Let $k$ be a field, $f(x,y) \in \bar{k}[x,y]$ an irreducible polynomial. Define $C_f := \bar{k}[x,y]/(f)$ and $\bar{k}(Z_f) = Frac(C_f)$.

Now, there is an equality and a claim that I can not understand how and any help will be appreciated:

1. $\bar{k}(Z_f) = (\bar{k}(x)[y])/(f)$
2. $\bar{k}(Z_f) $ is an extension of $\bar{k}(x)$ of degree $f$.

Comment: Is $f$ irreducible?

Comment: It is not mentioned but I will assume that it is, otherwise $C_f$ will not be a domain.

Comment: You can view $f$ as the minimal polynomial of $y$ over $Frac(\overline{k}[x])$. That gives the claim provided that $f$ contains a term of the form $a y^n$, $n=\deg f$, $a\neq0$. In other words, you want the degree of $f$ as a polynomial in $\overline{k}(x)[y]$.

Comment: How can I view $f$ as you said?

Comment: You want to make $f$ monic as polynomial in $y$. So for example if $f(x,y)=1+x^3+x^2y^5$ you think of it as
$$y^5+x+\frac1x\in k(x)[y].$$ That is, degree five rather than seven.
It is then the minimal polynomial (over $\overline{k}(x)$) of the function gotten by restricting $y$ to $Z_f$.

Comment: I see. What happens if we have more than one $y$ terms, like $f(x,y)=1+xy+y^2$?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Polynomials in $x$ are just coefficients. The example you wrote is just $y^2 + (x)\cdot y +1$, a quadratic in $y$ over $\bar k[x]$